# Cell TextLabel multiline not working anymore

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a project from a year ago that worked.

I have coded:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Multiline
```

to enable multiline text in UITableView cell, and it worked before on iOS 5 (not tested it since beginning of 2012), now the multiline doesn't work, and shows only 2 rows of text in cell.

Did I miss something in iOS 6? Was there some kind of change or bug that causes this?

**EDIT:** I've tried cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 5; for testing purposes, and it shows 2 rows again

Comment: If you were using UILineBreakModeWordWrap, it was deprecated in iSO 6.  Use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0 instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: As far as I know the only thing deprecated in iOS6 is UILineBreakModeWordWrap. NSLineBreakByWordWrapping is the iOS6 equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Write inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UILabel *lbl        = [[UILabel alloc]init];
lbl.text            = @"Your text value";
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
//Set frame according to string
CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT)
                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 0 , size.width , size.height)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
```

Your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method should be like this

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *value     = [listOfData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize stringSize = [value sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0] constrainedToSize:boundingSize  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return ((stringSize.height>44.00)?stringSize.height:44.00);
}
```

*Note: Things you need to change*

1. Here 300 is width of label . You can place your width here
2. Your can also change X and Y if it is dynamically added.

Answer (score 1):

UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated in iOS 6. Use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display you `cell` text with multiple then you can also put `UILabel` on `cell.contentView`, and give `labelName.numberOfLines = 0` for display text tin multi line.

**For EX:**

```
UILabel *lbltitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 270, 35)];
lbltitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
NSString *originalString = @" Indian version of this popular search engine. Search the whole web or only webpages from India. Interfaces offered in English, Hindi, Bengali, Telugu, Marathi";
lbltitle.text= originalString;
lbltitle.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:16];
lbltitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
lbltitle.numberOfLines = 0;
lbltitle.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbltitle];
```

Above code is put on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in between

```
if(cell == nil)
{
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

  // Put here Label Code  
}
```

Alos read this [How do I create a multiline table cell in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951731/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-table-cell-in-ios)

Comment: It does not change the size of the cell, text goes beyond cell rect

Comment: you can set size of cell as you need.

Comment: @1337code- in you case you not need to change size of cell only give size of label as i describe in my code :)

Comment: @1337code-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951731/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-table-cell-in-ios